# PIG : Index in REGEX_EXTRACT(line, '\\w{2}', 1);

Tags: regex, apache-pig

input :

```
1 XDi AL LO LOL
LOVEISALL
OP
LO
OPW
```

**Code**

```
a = load 'input' as (line:chararray);
b = foreach a generate REGEX_EXTRACT(line, '\\w{2}', 0);
dump b;
```

I would like to extract, if the input files has two characters on it.

**Output** :

```
(XD)
(LO)
(OP)
(LO)
(OP)
```

I could understand the explanation of the index of regex in the pig documents. what does that value of 0 or 1. Does that mean the position of the word in the line scalar ? 
If yes, I have given 0, so it should look for the first occurance of the word in line. but it scans the complete row.

Is someone has an idea of this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
a = load 'input' as (line:chararray);
b = foreach a generate REGEX_EXTRACT(line, '(^\\w{2}$)', 1) AS result;
c = FILTER b BY result is not null;
dump c;

Output:
(OP)
(LO)
```

Comment: your Regex pattern is correct, Thanks. Pls let me know the reason for mentioning 1 in the index.

Comment: 1 means return the string that matched in the first capturing group (). For example my regex is something like that REGEX_EXTRACT(line, '(\\w{2})(\\w{2})(\\w{2})', 2). In this case my output will be 2nd capturing group.